Github action, build just changed csproj
I have a huge .net solution that we recently migrated to github and we are trying to run code coverage on each PR. The issue is it currently takes about 30 minutes to run everything. We have multiple projects, with build dependencies, then we have to run the tests then is the gate quality from SonarQube. We can remove the sonar step and figure maybe a faster way to show code coverage results, but the issue is the build and running the tests. Is there a way to run only those projects that were changed? Right now I am always building the base projects.
